# Problem with latest QGIS 2.18.23

Tags: qgis

I updated my QGIS 2.18.11 version with latest QGIS 2.18.23.

I have a problem, I can open my old projects, but when I try to zoom in or zoom out with the mouse wheel, everything disappears, and QGIS  tries to refresh the screen, which never refreshes. When I try to close QGIS,  not responding and freeze screen.

Comment: Are you using the TileLayer plugin? It is a known bug that won't be fixed.

Comment: No, I do not use this plugin. It is generally much slower in refreshment. Just now I tried to save selected lines to new layer, and QGIS freeze again.

Comment: Sometimes plugins can cause freezing issues. Try opening a blank project in QGIS. Disable all the plugins. Then open one of your old projects and see if you have the freezing issue. If the issue doesn't occur, enable the plugins one at a time and keep testing until you find the one that caused the issue.

Comment: Also try removing or disabling any web-based layers.

Comment: I did it everything you said and same again. I tried with QGIS 2.18.22 and the same again. I reverted to older version 2.18.11 and work fine for now. Probably, something incompatible with window 10 latest update

Comment: I solved the problem. Something is wrong with the x64 bit version. I installed the x32 bit version. Thank you for your help.